# Wordpress How to change comments form its default (an empty text box) to another one with some fixed text?

Tags: php, wordpress, comments

Wordpress comments is just an empty text box. I need to include some fixed text inside that box.

For example instead of just allow user to do free comments to an article, I wish that the text box of these comments already filled with 3 questions to encourage reader to reply these questions.

Comment: Much better if you could provide codes of what you have done so far. It would help others to assist you with your concern.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by adding Custom fields in your comment form.

You can add custom fields either by using a plugin or by custom code.

***Option 1: Using Plugin***

https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-comment-fields/

***Option 2: Custom Code***

This below slideshow should be able to show you how:

[Hooking into Comments](https://www.slideshare.net/beaulebens/hooking-into-comments-5047868)

And this blog post will provide more info on this:

[WordPress 3.0 Theme Tip: The Comment Form](http://ottopress.com/2010/wordpress-3-0-theme-tip-the-comment-form/)

Comment: I don't need to add and extra custom field. I just need that the blank text box that is used by wordpress to allow user's comments allow me to add some fix text. So the user see that text and write something. But the idea is the text is inside the blank text box.

Comment: I don´t need to add an extra custom field. Just I need to transform the blank comment text box in another one with some fixed text and of course bellow this text users write their comments.